# How to split textbox value then display splitted value on label

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0

How to split a text box (delimited by "-") value then display the split values on two labels?

Heres my code:

```
    Dim s As String
    Dim substring As String
    Dim sp() As String

    s = txtTime1.Text 'this text box contains value (08:00-17:41)
    sp = s.Split("-")

    For Each substring In sp
        txtTimeIn.Text = substring
        txtTimeOut.Text = substring
    Next
```

My problem is txtTimeIn and txtTimeOut displays only value '17:41'. Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Dim s As String
Dim substring As String
Dim sp() As String

s = txtTime1.Text 'this text box contains value (08:00-17:41)
sp = s.Split("-")

txtTimeIn.Text = sp(0)
txtTimeOut.Text = sp(1)
```

Comment: Well i did research more :) here's the link for future researchers http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mw5OF3QoZms cheers bro!